# Simulating a Mouse Event on A Minimized Window Java

Tags: java, background, mouse

So I want to be able to simulate mouse clicks on my window/frame, but in the background. This means I cant use the Robot class because it takes control of the OSes mouse which is not what I want (please guys, I know of and use the Robot class, it's not what I need).

I want the program to think I clicked on part of it (x,y on the frame) even when minimized (doesnt have to minimized but at least out of focus). I dont want it to take over my computer since it should ideally be a background task.

I did a little bit of research before posting and I read that I could make an Applet and then use the "reflection class"(?) and mouselisteners to invoke mouse events on the frame itself rather than through the OS. Not sure if itll work cause the explanation was pretty meh and the guy said they could communicate individually if he had problems :/.

Kind of wondering if it's possible at this point. If it cant be done in java, I know a little python, so if  there's a solution for it in python, that could work to.

TLDR: Need to simulate mouseclicks on my frame, but it cant use the os mouse and should ideally work when the application is out of focus/in the background.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You could look into [`Component#dispatchEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent))

Comment: You could also look into [`EventQueue#postEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#postEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent)), but that's getting into dark places..

Comment: Tried the dispatch event. I made this simple window that dispatches the event at the location 20,20 or whatever and it seems to be working, but the problem is that when I put a button in front of where it clicks, it doesnt actually click the button :/. I want it to click whatever is in front of it.

Comment: I think that once dispatchEvent is called on a component, the coordinates are already converted to local context space. Also, you should be dispatching the event directly to the component you want notified, otherwise you'll have to the EventQueue approach...